# Why this constructor argument is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, constructor, google-cloud-bigtable

I created a new class with below piece of logic.

```
import com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.stub.EnhancedBigtableStubSettings;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.threeten.bp.Duration;

@Component
@RefreshScope
public class PrimeChannel {

    private final EnhancedBigtableStubSettings enhancedBigtableStubSettings;
    private final List<String> tableIds;

    public PrimeChannel(EnhancedBigtableStubSettings enhancedBigtableStubSettings, List<String> tableIds) {
        this.enhancedBigtableStubSettings = enhancedBigtableStubSettings;
        this.tableIds = tableIds;
    }
}
```

While running i am getting below error

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in myPackage.PrimeChannel required a bean of type 'com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.stub.EnhancedBigtableStubSettings' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.stub.EnhancedBigtableStubSettings' in your configuration.
```

I am passing EnhancedBigtableStubSettings object as first parameter then why its not considering.

if i try with 0 argument constructor by initializing EnhancedBigtableStubSettings as null will throws null pointer exception in later stages.

How can deal with this?

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: What's unclear? Your Spring context doesn't have the bean that the constructor needs.

Comment: "I am passing EnhancedBigtableStubSettings object as first parameter then why its not considering." Do you call `new PrimeChannel()` somewhere in your code? If so, yous hould show it. I think you don't do this explictly and are using dependency injection instead.

Comment: I couldn't create bean for  EnhancedBigtableStubSettings  as it has private access. Actually i am trying to implement [this](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable/blob/main/google-cloud-bigtable/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/data/v2/stub/BigtableChannelPrimer.java) logic as a seperate class. In this example that import is not mentioned but i could import from `import com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.stub.EnhancedBigtableStubSettings;`

Comment: The sample you link to uses a builder to build a `EnhancedBigtableStubSettings`. Put that in an `@Bean` method to create an instance of that specific type.

Comment: i tried both methods 1) `@Bean
    private EnhancedBigtableStubSettings.Builder settingsTemplate(){
        return new EnhancedBigtableStubSettings.Builder();
    }` in that i got error `'Builder()' has private access in 'com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.stub.EnhancedBigtableStubSettings.Builder'` 2) `@Bean
    private EnhancedBigtableStubSettings settingsTemplate(){
        return EnhancedBigtableStubSettings.newBuilder().build();
    }` this didn't throw any error but how can i new builder data in constructor?

Comment: make the method public and the settings will be automatically inserted by Spring.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you must create a bean of EnhancedBigtableStubSettings class. You can define it in applicationContext.xml or @Configuration class, then annotate the constructor with @Autowired.

```
<bean name="beanName" class="foo.EnhancedBigtableStubSettings"/>

@Bean(name = "beanName")
public EnhancedBigtableStubSettings getEnhancedBigtableStubSettings() {
    //return object somehow
    return new EnhancedBigtableStubSettings();
}
```

Comment: It is not necessary to use `@Autowired` if there is only one constructor.

Comment: I couldn't create bean for  EnhancedBigtableStubSettings  as it has private access. Actually i am trying to implement [this](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable/blob/main/google-cloud-bigtable/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/data/v2/stub/BigtableChannelPrimer.java) logic as a seperate class. In this example that import is not mentioned but i could import from `import com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.stub.EnhancedBigtableStubSettings;`